# Django-Haystack returns no results in search form

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using Django-Haystack with Whoosh backend. When I do a query I get no results. I tried the debugging steps suggested in the Haystack docs by typing the following into a Django shell, and I can see that all the text I want has been indexed.

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
sqs.count()
sqs[0].text
```

My search.html page has the following section (copied straight from the documentation):

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
    <p>
        <a href="{{ result.object.url }}">{{ result.object }}</a>
    </p>
{% empty %}
    <p>No results found.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have no idea what's happening, but whereas in the examples `page.object_list` works, in my real project I needed to remove the `page` prefix. Painful to figure out.

Now this works:

```
{% for result in object_list %}
  <p>
    <a href="{{ result.object.url }}">{{ result.object }}</a>
  </p>
{% empty %}
  <p>No results found.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a noobie trying out django-haystack and whoosh, and following fragments of various tutorials on haystack's docs, I had the same problem as you:
No results were showing up when I did an EmptySearch(), even though I had  overridden SearchForm to show all.

```
def no_query_found(self):
    return self.searchqueryset.all()
```

As you say, removing the "page" prefix on the search.html template did the trick, and was a good temporary solution.  However, it became a problem when it was time to paginate the results. So after looking around, the solution was to use the "page_obj" prefix instead of "page" and everything works as expected.  It seems the issue is that the haystack-tutorial assumes the page object is called "page", while certain versions of django its called "page_obj"?  I'm sure there is a better answer - I'm just reporting my limited findings.